# How to enforce https on client/browsers

Tags: web-server, https

My web application is on `GCP` and accepts requests on both `http` and `https`. I want to enforce `https` only connections without creating friction in user experience.

If I remove `http` then I am afraid that a user typing `http://mywebapp.com` will get `404`. Should the right approach be to accept requests on both `http` and `https` and redirect `http` requests (`303`) so that the client send the request again using `https`?

- Is doing above possible?
- Wouldn't that increase my traffic cost (on `gcp` due to redirection/duplicate requests)
- Is there some other better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: If you don't want to block port 80, then you will need to redirect.  Simple as that.

Answer (score 3):

You set up both HTTP and HTTPS listeners. You configure your HTTP listener to answer the client with a 301 permanent redirect. You set up your HTTPS listener to send an HSTS header to make standards compliant clients only ever attempt HTTPS connections in the future. Each client will only attempt the HTTP listener once and then use the HTTPS one until they’ve forgotten about your service or until the HSTS lifetime runs out without being renewed.